# Is it possible to compile TypeScript into minified code?

Tags: typescript, minify

Is there an option to compile TypeScript code's output as minified? Or are we left to deal with that in a separate process? And does obfuscation affect the answer?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

The TypeScript compiler does not support the generation of minified or obfuscated code. you will need to use another tool against the JavaScript output of the compiler.

There's an open feature request: [microsoft/TypeScript#8](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8)

Comment: You can use YUI Compressor, JSMin or Closure Compiler to minify JS code.

Comment: that's what I ended up doing. I added a post-compile command passing the app.js file to the YUI compressor so that I essentially got compilation-time minification.

Comment: Web Essentials can do it automatically from your ts'es.

Comment: as @joeriks says, download WebEssentials2012, it can automatically create a min.js version of your file

Comment: This is so bad. It sounds a very reasonable to produce minified code with the appropriate .map, if the all infrastructure is given in the TypeScript compiler. Also in VS case it could be a fully integrated solution, even a configuration setting.

Answer (score 30):

I am the author of [typescript-closure-compiler](https://github.com/sagifogel/typescript-closure-compiler).
Basically it is a tool that emits files that are compatible with google closure compiler, which is probably the best minifier/optimizer/obfuscator out there.
I've also created a [playground](http://sagifogel.github.io/typescript-closure-compiler/) that can show you the generated output.
You can take a look at an example [project](https://github.com/sagifogel/TSFunq) which uses this tool.
The minification process is done using gulp.

Comment: playground is broken

Comment: Last version support typescript 1.8.1. So i think this is deprecated.

Comment: not maintained from 2017

Answer (score 9):

The industry standard for minification is `esbuild`. ([link](https://esbuild.github.io))

Call `esbuild` after compiling to Javascript

```
esbuild your_file.js --minify --outfile=your_file.min.js
```

An example one liner:

```
tsc --strict --lib DOM,DOM.Iterable,ES6 --target ES6 your_file.ts && esbuild your_file.js --minify --outfile=your_file.min.js
```