# TypeScript Obfuscation

Tags: obfuscation, typescript

Are there any tools or forks of TypeScript to support public namespace obfuscation? I.e. to turn:

```
class MyUtil {
   print(): void { ... }
}
```

Into something like:

```
class xxy {
   aab(): void { ... }
}
```

If not, would be be straight forward to fork the compiler to provide this? Perhaps with some type of class annotation indication what should / shouldn't be obfuscated.

(Obviously public obfuscation has to be used carefully, no good for libraries! But great if used consistently across your project)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12682268/is-it-possible-to-compile-typescript-into-minified-code.

Comment: "mangle" option with a JS Uglify package on your Javascript Output, can be done with Webpack using UglifyJsPlugin

Answer (score 23):

I had the exact same question, and it was instantly deleted by SO.

https://github.com/angular/ts-minify

This is exactly the tool you (and I) are looking for, it seems to work pretty well, I needed to comment out a few parts where the the author was taking precautions I don't think are applicable.

Comment: The most likely reason why your question was closed is because you were asking for tool recommendations, which is specifically not appropriate for SO. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question

Comment: I really still feel like ts-minify is the answer you seek, have you tried it and it doesnt work?

Comment: Asking for _tools_ is one of the ways to ask for _ways_. Programmatically speaking, `Tools extends Ways`. It is not inappropriate. I don't get it. Upvoted this one.

Answer (score 10):

I don't believe there is any reason to do this in TypeScript. You can instead use something like Closure Compiler to do the obfuscation on your JavaScript output. Specifically look into Closure's [Advanced Compilation](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3) settings.

Comment: I appreciate it could be done on plain JS with other tools. But I think it makes sense to do it as part of the TS compiler, it will reduce the number of separate tools you need to install if nothing else. I'd like to see TS offering minification and obfuscation options.

Comment: It absolutely makes sense for Typescript to 'know' about obfuscation. I want to be forced to explicitly mark properties as 'public' (or exported or whatever) that I need exposed to my HTML page. For instance I'm using Knockout and I need to bind to some properties on the viewmodel but not all, or maybe I have private functions. If Typescript could handle this for me I'd get much more efficient code where a standard obfuscator may not have enough information to make the decision.

Comment: If you ship TypeScript code for production, then this is valid. You may be using `ts-node` for on-the-fly transpilation (which isn't as slow as you might imagine), or running your app in a TypeScript interpreter like Deno (https://github.com/denoland/deno), etc.

Answer (score 2):

## Not a direct answer! Js obfuscator

https://github.com/javascript-obfuscator/javascript-obfuscator

> Plugins:
>
> ```
> Webpack plugin: webpack-obfuscator
> Webpack loader: obfuscator-loader
> Gulp: gulp-javascript-obfuscator
> Grunt: grunt-contrib-obfuscator
> Rollup: rollup-plugin-javascript-obfuscator
> ```

NOTE:

> Only obfuscate the code that belongs to you.
>
> It is not recommended to obfuscate vendor scripts and polyfills, since
> **the obfuscated code is 15-80% slower (depends on options) and the
> files are significantly larger.**