# How to Obfuscate NestJS

Tags: nestjs

I am using nest.js and I am trying to obfuscate the code in the dist folder. I tried various solutions but none of them seems to work. They all fail when I bootstrap the server(main.js file)

Is there any recommend tool that I can use that is working properly?

Comment: Can you share snippets of you code for more clarity?

Comment: I think the answer that you are looking is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14102242/typescript-obfuscation

Answer (score 2):

Due to how Nest works with typescript reflection and class names, obfuscation often leads changing the names of classes which makes the reflection system not work in the same way. Usually you don't need to worry about obfuscating server side code because it isn't publicly visible.

Comment: Yes that is what I thought but still it's a concern for me. Is there any other way around it? It doesn't have to be 100% obfuscating.

Comment: I don't know of any partial obfuscators. What's the reason for needing server side obfuscation?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel What if you are deploying the application on-premise, your code resides on someone else's server?

Comment: @Tanmay it doesn't change my answer. Most of the time there isn't a need for code-obfuscation on the server side.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I did it using [javascript-obfuscator](https://github.com/javascript-obfuscator/javascript-obfuscator).

1. `npm i -D javascript-obfuscator`
2. Update `tsconfig.json`, set `outDir` to `./dist_raw`
3. Update `package.json`, set `scripts.build` to `nest build && javascript-obfuscator dist_raw --output dist --target node`
4. Update `.gitignore`, add line `/dist_raw`
5. `npm run build`

Simply change typescript complation output to `./dist_raw` and run `javascript-obfuscator` to produce final `./dist` folder.